# Kentor.Authservices - GetExternalLoginInfoAsync returns null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin, saml-2.0, okta, kentor-authservices

I am using Okta as Identity provider. Implemented the Owin middleware in MVC 
    Application. After registering the application in Okta with SAML2 as the 
    protocol, trying to connect to okta from Owin middleware using 
    Kentor.Authservices. I am not using identity server3.

```
    var authServicesOktaOptions = new KentorAuthServicesAuthenticationOptions(false)
    {
         SPOptions = new SPOptions
         {
               AuthenticateRequestSigningBehavior = SigningBehavior.Never,
               EntityId = new EntityId("http://core/Account/ExternalLoginCallback"),
                        ReturnUrl = new Uri("http://core/Account/ExternalLoginCallback"),
                    },
                    AuthenticationType = "Login With <CompanyName>",
                    Caption = "Login With <CompanyName>",
                };

                var idpOkta = new IdentityProvider(new EntityId("http://www.okta.com/exk2bm6xe5eT3jQkN1t6"), authServicesOktaOptions.SPOptions)
                {
                    LoadMetadata = true,
                    MetadataLocation = "https://<companyname>.okta.com/app/exk2bm6xe5eT3jQkN1t6/sso/saml/metadata",
                    Binding = Saml2BindingType.HttpRedirect,
                    AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true,
                    SingleSignOnServiceUrl = new Uri("https://<companyname>.okta.com/app/<companyname>_test<appname>withokta_1/exk2bm6xe5eT3jQkN1t6/sso/saml"),
                };

    authServicesOktaOptions.IdentityProviders.Add(idpOkta);
    app.UseKentorAuthServicesAuthentication(authServicesOktaOptions);
```

In the Controller in the ExternalCallback function I am expecting the userLoginInfo details

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
   var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
}
```

But the loginIfo is always going null.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Also having this issue .... On an integration environment. Locally all works fine?!?